# Building a Higher order Component and applying it to redux connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Please consider the React Native code:

**MyForm.js**

```
Class MyForm extends Component{
   render(){
      //Code Left out for simplicity
   }
} 

function mapStateToProps(){//code left out for simplicity}

MyForm.propTypes = {//code left out for simplicity};
export default(connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(withHocComponent(MyForm)));
```

**HoComponent.js**

```
export default withHocComponent = WrappedComponent => class HoComponent extends Component {
    class HocComponent extends Component{
       render(){
         <View>
           <WrappedComponent/>
         </View>
       }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
  prop1: state.myReducer.someProp,
 };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withHocComponent);
```

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot call class as a function.

The stack is referring to this line: `export default(connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(withHocComponent(MyForm)));`

I am trying to implement an additional Higher order component besides the redux `connect` function.

Comment: Do you want to contect your HOC to the redux store ?

Comment: @TimH good question. The Hoc should also get data from the redux store

Comment: I found the nested component very weird, is it a typo in the post ? The way you want to do it is probably: `const withHocComponent = wrapped => () => (<View> <Wrapped /> </View>);` An HOC is a function that returns a component. In that way, you have the function `withHocComponent` that returns a "stateless component" but it would work the same with a statefull component

Comment: @sanders i tried to answer your question below.

Comment: I think you have a typo (not sure if this is just in SO or your actual code) where you have the `class HoComponent extends Component` twice.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i hope this is what you are looking for. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

**HOC**

```
function withHocComponent(WrappedComponent) {
    class Wrapper extends Component {
        render() {
            // here you could pass props to your wrappedComponent
            return <WrappedComponent />;
         }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
           //code left out for simplicity
        }
        //connect your HOC to the store inside the Wrapper 
        return connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Wrapper);
     }
}
export default withHocComponent;
```

**MyForm**

```
Class MyForm extends Component{
   render(){
      //Code Left out for simplicity
   }
} 

function mapStateToProps(){//code left out for simplicity}

MyForm.propTypes = {//code left out for simplicity};

// Here is the part where the magic happens. 
// Pass your HOC your connected component
export default withHocComponent(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(MyForm));
```

Comment: greate answer, simply and easy to understand

Comment: @VnDevil Thank you. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TimH,
I changed it up a bit by putting the class, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps inside the HOC, I could not get it to work when they were inside the HOCComponent.

```
const HOC = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class HOCComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                talking: false
            };
        }
        render() {
            return (<WrappedComponent speak={this.speak} />);
        }
    }


    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        start: state.lessonStartReducer.start,
    });


    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        startLesson: (payload) => {
            dispatch(startLesson(payload));
        },
    });


    return connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(HOCComponent);
}
export default HOC;
```